# How to download JDK for Android programming

Tags: android, development, jdk

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit. I'm going to start programming for android devices.

I know that I will need to install a JDK, but I don't have access to oracle.com.

How do I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any help you need can probably be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java).

So, install by doing

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Comment: The package is about 80mb, the speed of software center and terminal is low, is there any links that i can download with download manager?

Comment: so? It'll only take 10 minutes to download, depending on your connection.

Comment: i'm using 2 mega high speed, but download rate is about 20 kbps! it's not real speed, is there any links?

Comment: 20kbps is alright for this kind of thing, just let it download while you read a book or something.

Comment: but my download manager speed is about 500 kbps, ok thanks

Comment: Welcome. If I helped, please choose my answer, or upvote me, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Type below commands on terminal.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```